# Need to format and create an NSString

Tags: amazon-s3, nsstring

I need to create an NSString that equals, 
current year-month-day-hour(24)-minute-second-milisecond.filetype

This will plug into this NSstring

```
NSString *filename   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d", imageNo] ofType:@"png"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter new];
    df.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-S";
    NSLog(@"%@",[df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

Comment: where are you getting "shan" from?

Comment: Sorry that was a test